# Educational implementation of SHA256 in Rust

Tags: beginner, reinventing-the-wheel, rust, cryptography

A few weeks ago I decided to have a look at the Rust programming language. After  a few standard exercises I chose to try to implement the SHA256 hashing algorithm, because why not.

The algorithm's state is stored in a struct, similar to Python's hashlib. This is the `lib.rs` file:

```rust
use std::convert::TryInto;


pub struct SHA256Hash {
    h0: u32,
    h1: u32,
    h2: u32,
    h3: u32,
    h4: u32,
    h5: u32,
    h6: u32,
    h7: u32,
    finalized: bool,
    total_bits: usize,
    unprocessed_bytes: Vec<u8>,
    input_block_size: usize
}


impl SHA256Hash {

    /// Create a new hash instance
    pub fn new() -> SHA256Hash {
        SHA256Hash {
            h0: 0x6a09e667,
            h1: 0xbb67ae85,
            h2: 0x3c6ef372,
            h3: 0xa54ff53a,
            h4: 0x510e527f,
            h5: 0x9b05688c,
            h6: 0x1f83d9ab,
            h7: 0x5be0cd19,
            finalized: false,
            total_bits: 0,
            unprocessed_bytes: Vec::new(),
            input_block_size: 64
        }
    }

    pub fn block_size(&self) -> usize {
        self.input_block_size
    }

    /// update with a block of 512bit
    fn update_block(&mut self, block: &[u8; 64]) {

        // Initialize array of round constants:
        // (first 32 bits of the fractional parts of the cube roots of the first 64 primes 2..311):
        let round_constants: [u32; 64] = [
            0x428a2f98, 0x71374491, 0xb5c0fbcf, 0xe9b5dba5, 0x3956c25b, 0x59f111f1, 0x923f82a4, 0xab1c5ed5,
            0xd807aa98, 0x12835b01, 0x243185be, 0x550c7dc3, 0x72be5d74, 0x80deb1fe, 0x9bdc06a7, 0xc19bf174,
            0xe49b69c1, 0xefbe4786, 0x0fc19dc6, 0x240ca1cc, 0x2de92c6f, 0x4a7484aa, 0x5cb0a9dc, 0x76f988da,
            0x983e5152, 0xa831c66d, 0xb00327c8, 0xbf597fc7, 0xc6e00bf3, 0xd5a79147, 0x06ca6351, 0x14292967,
            0x27b70a85, 0x2e1b2138, 0x4d2c6dfc, 0x53380d13, 0x650a7354, 0x766a0abb, 0x81c2c92e, 0x92722c85,
            0xa2bfe8a1, 0xa81a664b, 0xc24b8b70, 0xc76c51a3, 0xd192e819, 0xd6990624, 0xf40e3585, 0x106aa070,
            0x19a4c116, 0x1e376c08, 0x2748774c, 0x34b0bcb5, 0x391c0cb3, 0x4ed8aa4a, 0x5b9cca4f, 0x682e6ff3,
            0x748f82ee, 0x78a5636f, 0x84c87814, 0x8cc70208, 0x90befffa, 0xa4506ceb, 0xbef9a3f7, 0xc67178f2
        ];

        let mut w: [u32; 64] = [0; 64];

        for j in 0..16 {
            // let mut bytes: [u8; 4] = Default::default();
            // bytes.copy_from_slice(&block[j*4..(j+1)*4]);
            // w[j] = transform_array_of_u8_big_endian_to_u32(&bytes);
            w[j] = transform_array_of_u8_big_endian_to_u32(block[j*4..(j+1)*4].try_into().expect(""));
            // println!("w[{:2}] {:08X?}", j, w[j]);
        }

        // Extend the first 16 words into the remaining 48 words w[16..63] of the message schedule array:
        for j in 16..64 {
            let s0 = w[j-15].rotate_right(7) ^ w[j-15].rotate_right(18) ^ (w[j-15] >> 3);
            let s1 = w[j-2].rotate_right(17) ^ w[j-2].rotate_right(19) ^ (w[j-2] >> 10);
            w[j] = w[j-16].wrapping_add(s0).wrapping_add(w[j-7]).wrapping_add(s1);
        }

        let mut a = self.h0;
        let mut b = self.h1;
        let mut c = self.h2;
        let mut d = self.h3;
        let mut e = self.h4;
        let mut f = self.h5;
        let mut g = self.h6;
        let mut h = self.h7;

        // Compression function main loop:
        for j in 0..64 {
            let s1 = e.rotate_right(6) ^ e.rotate_right(11) ^ e.rotate_right(25);
            let ch = (e & f) ^ (!e & g);
            let temp1 = h.wrapping_add(s1).wrapping_add(ch).wrapping_add(round_constants[j]).wrapping_add(w[j]);

            let s0 = a.rotate_right(2) ^ a.rotate_right(13) ^ a.rotate_right(22);
            let maj = (a & b) ^ (a & c) ^ (b & c);
            let temp2 = s0.wrapping_add(maj);

            h = g;
            g = f;
            f = e;
            e = d.wrapping_add(temp1);
            d = c;
            c = b;
            b = a;
            a = temp1.wrapping_add(temp2);
        }

        self.h0 = self.h0.wrapping_add(a);
        self.h1 = self.h1.wrapping_add(b);
        self.h2 = self.h2.wrapping_add(c);
        self.h3 = self.h3.wrapping_add(d);
        self.h4 = self.h4.wrapping_add(e);
        self.h5 = self.h5.wrapping_add(f);
        self.h6 = self.h6.wrapping_add(g);
        self.h7 = self.h7.wrapping_add(h);
    }

    /// consume blocks of unprocessed bytes
    fn consume(&mut self) {
        assert_eq!(self.unprocessed_bytes.len() % 64, 0);
        let n_blocks = self.unprocessed_bytes.len() / 64;
        for i in 0..n_blocks {
            let mut block: [u8; 64] = [0; 64];
            // the copy seems to be necessary because of a multiple
            // mutable/immutable borowing situation I've set up for myself
            block.copy_from_slice(&self.unprocessed_bytes[i*64..(i+1)*64]);
            self.update_block(&block);
            // it's a pitty that try_into does not work here
        }
        self.unprocessed_bytes.clear();
    }

    /// query the hash digest
    pub fn digest(&mut self) -> [u32; 8] {
        self.finalize();
        [self.h0, self.h1, self.h2, self.h3, self.h4, self.h5, self.h6, self.h7]
    }

    /// query the hex digest, formatted as hexadecimal string
    pub fn hex_digest(&mut self) -> String {
        let digest = self.digest();
        format!(
            "{:08X?}{:08X?}{:08X?}{:08X?}{:08X?}{:08X?}{:08X?}{:08X?}",
            digest[0], digest[1], digest[2], digest[3],
            digest[4], digest[5], digest[6], digest[7]
        )
    }

    /// update the hash state
    pub fn update(&mut self, input: &[u8]) -> bool {
        if self.finalized || input.len() == 0 {
            return false;
        }

        let input_len_bytes = input.len();
        self.total_bits += input_len_bytes * 8;
        let remaining_bytes = (input_len_bytes + self.unprocessed_bytes.len()) % 64;
        self.unprocessed_bytes.extend(input[..(input_len_bytes-remaining_bytes)].iter().clone());

        self.consume();

        if remaining_bytes > 0 {
            self.unprocessed_bytes.extend(input[input_len_bytes-remaining_bytes..].iter().clone());
        }

        true
    }

    fn finalize(&mut self) {
        self.unprocessed_bytes.push(0x80);

        let n_padding_bits = 512 - (self.total_bits + 8 + 64) % 512;
        let n_padding_bytes = n_padding_bits / 8;
        self.unprocessed_bytes.extend(vec![0; n_padding_bytes]);
        let length: u64 = self.total_bits.try_into().unwrap();
        self.unprocessed_bytes.extend(&transform_u64_to_array_of_u8_big_endian(length));

        self.consume();

        self.finalized = true;
    }
}

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

fn transform_u64_to_array_of_u8_big_endian(x: u64) -> [u8; 8] {
    let b1 = ((x >> 56) & 0xff) as u8;
    let b2 = ((x >> 48) & 0xff) as u8;
    let b3 = ((x >> 40) & 0xff) as u8;
    let b4 = ((x >> 32) & 0xff) as u8;
    let b5 = ((x >> 24) & 0xff) as u8;
    let b6 = ((x >> 16) & 0xff) as u8;
    let b7 = ((x >> 8) & 0xff) as u8;
    let b8 = (x & 0xff) as u8;
    [b1, b2, b3, b4, b5, b6, b7, b8]
}


fn transform_array_of_u8_big_endian_to_u32(arr_of_u8: &[u8; 4]) -> u32 {
    let mut x: u32 = 0;
    x |= (arr_of_u8[0] as u32) << 24;
    x |= (arr_of_u8[1] as u32) << 16;
    x |= (arr_of_u8[2] as u32) << 8;
    x |= arr_of_u8[3] as u32;
    x
}

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use super::SHA256Hash;

    /// Run empty test input from FIPS 180-2
    #[test]
    fn sha256_nist_empty() {
        let mut hasher = SHA256Hash::new();
        hasher.update(&[]);
        let digest = hasher.digest();
        assert_eq!(
            digest,
            [0xe3b0c442, 0x98fc1c14, 0x9afbf4c8, 0x996fb924,
             0x27ae41e4, 0x649b934c, 0xa495991b, 0x7852b855]
        );
    }

    /// Run abc test from FIPS 180-2
    #[test]
    fn sha256_nist_abc() {
        let mut hasher = SHA256Hash::new();
        hasher.update(b"abc");
        let digest = hasher.digest();
        assert_eq!(
            digest,
            [0xba7816bf, 0x8f01cfea, 0x414140de, 0x5dae2223,
             0xb00361a3, 0x96177a9c, 0xb410ff61, 0xf20015ad]
        )
    }

    /// Run two-block test from FIPS 180-2
    #[test]
    fn sha256_nist_two_blocks() {
        let mut hasher = SHA256Hash::new();
        hasher.update(b"abcdbcdecdefdefgefghfghighijhijkijkljklmklmnlmnomnopnopq");
        let digest = hasher.digest();
        assert_eq!(
            digest,
            [0x248d6a61, 0xd20638b8, 0xe5c02693, 0x0c3e6039,
             0xa33ce459, 0x64ff2167, 0xf6ecedd4, 0x19db06c1]
        );
    }

    /// Run large input test (1,000,000 x a) from FIPS 180-2
    #[test]
    fn sha256_nist_large_input() {
        let input_str = std::iter::repeat("a").take(1_000_000).collect::<String>();
        let input = input_str.as_bytes();
        let mut hasher = SHA256Hash::new();
        hasher.update(&input);
        let digest = hasher.digest();
        assert_eq!(
            digest,
            [0xcdc76e5c, 0x9914fb92, 0x81a1c7e2, 0x84d73e67,
             0xf1809a48, 0xa497200e, 0x046d39cc, 0xc7112cd0]
        );
    }
}
```

`lib.rs` comes with a small suite of unit tests as specified in [FIPS 180-2](https://csrc.nist.gov/CSRC/media/Publications/fips/180/2/archive/2002-08-01/documents/fips180-2withchangenotice.pdf) Appendix B. The test suite can be run using `cargo test [--release]`

Then there is also `main.rs` which generates an executable to be used a command-line tool:

```rust
use std::env;
use std::fs::File;
use std::io::{BufRead, BufReader};

use sha256::SHA256Hash;


fn main() -> std::io::Result<()> {
    let mut hasher = SHA256Hash::new();

    let args: Vec<String> = env::args().collect();
    if args.len() < 2 {
        eprintln!("Please provide a filename as command line argument!");
        return Ok(());
    }

    let filename = &args[1];
    let file = File::open(filename)?;
    let chunk_size: usize = hasher.block_size() * 1024;
    let mut reader = BufReader::with_capacity(chunk_size, file);

    loop {
        let length = {
            let buffer = reader.fill_buf()?;
            hasher.update(buffer);
            buffer.len()
        };
        if length == 0 {
            break;
        }
        reader.consume(length);
    }

    println!("{} {}", hasher.hex_digest().to_ascii_lowercase(), filename);

    Ok(())
}
```

As an example, let's compute the hash of lib.rs ;-)

```
cargo run --release src\lib.rs
86dccf89c7cb4de0837a2c4a3c709ae7845151338a1a21a8321fcbf9e4d8dcf7 src\lib.rs
```

Computing the hash for an ISO image of 3.64 GiB takes roughly 39s here on my laptop (35s with 7zip's built-in SHA256).

I'm open to all kinds of feedback, be it style, idiomatic rust, performance, usability, whatever comes to your mind.

---

`Cargo.toml` for completeness:

```
[package]
name = "hash_sha256"
version = "0.1.0"
authors = ["AlexV"]
edition = "2018"

[lib]
name = "sha256"
path = "src/lib.rs"
```

---

I'm aware of a [similar question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/221826/92478) here on Code Review, but unfortunately it has no answer. Also from what I can judge, the approaches are reasonably different to exist in their own right.

Comment: In preparation for a proper answer, I'm laying out an implementation trait and a `criterion` benchmark so we can profile your code together and find improvements. SHA256 is a good way to challenge your optimization skills, so it'll definitely be a fun challenge :-)

Comment: @SébastienRenauld: Take your time. A quick Google search on profiling in Rust earlier in my Rust endeavours left me a little bit disappointed, but the `criterion` crate sounds interesting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First off, let's start with a simple assumption: SIMD is off the table. As such, your kernel computation (`update_block`) is mostly optimized, and instead, I ended up focusing on the rest.

## Some bad news

After profiling, and as expected, the bulk of the CPU time of your SHA256 implementation is in `update_block()`. No real surprise there. As a result, we know ahead of time that we can do very little to ease the pains of the 64 rounds of operations without resorting to some devious trickery.

We can, however, make one simple change. We're going to pull in the `byteorder` crate and use it to convert our `u8` arrays into `u32`s. This will both ease our pain and provide a better version of what you already had. Since we're always feeding it 4 bytes (verifiable by code logic), we can safely drop the slice size prefix and benefit from the blanket `&[u8]` `Read` implementation.

It also looks neat and inlinable:

```
fn transform_array_of_u8_big_endian_to_u32(mut arr_of_u8: &[u8]) -> u32 {
    arr_of_u8.read_u32::<BigEndian>().unwrap()
}
```

## Some good news

There's a *ton* of allocations we can remove!

We're going to change the method signature of `consume` from `fn consume(&mut self);` to `fn consume(&mut self, bytes: &[u8]);`. The reason for this is the pretty neat performance gain we can score by doing the following ([**playground**](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=fb9ec52bdd7ace8ceeb2e8d79c5ef051)):

```rust
fn consume(&mut self, mut bytes: &[u8]) {
    let input_len_bytes = bytes.len();
    let unprocessed_len = self.unprocessed_bytes.len();
    self.total_bits += input_len_bytes * 8;
    // Do we have bytes in the unprocessed buffer?
    if unprocessed_len > 0 {
        if (unprocessed_len + input_len_bytes) < 64 {
            // Nothing to do, we just append
            // Copy up to 63 bytes to our Vec
            self.unprocessed_bytes.extend_from_slice(bytes);
            return;
        }
        let (additional, new_bytes) = bytes.split_at(64 - unprocessed_len);
        // Reassign
        bytes = new_bytes;
        // Copy up to 64 bytes from what we just took
        self.unprocessed_bytes.extend_from_slice(additional);
        // We can afford a 64-byte clone
        self.update_block(self.unprocessed_bytes.clone().as_slice());
        self.unprocessed_bytes.clear();
        // Call ourselves
        //return self.inner_consume(new_bytes);
    }
    let iter = bytes.chunks_exact(64);
    let remainder_i = iter.clone();
    for block in iter {
        self.update_block(&block)
    }
    let bytes = remainder_i.remainder();
    self.unprocessed_bytes.extend_from_slice(bytes); // max 64bytes allocated
}
```

This also opens up repeated calls to `update()`, something which the previous version fell over on (index out of bounds errors). The `chunks_exact()` iterator takes advantage that the slice is not mutable and quite literally just moves a pointer around. This both frees us from copies of the data and issues regarding ownership.

Honestly, after having a proper look at profiling data, that's as far as you'll go without venturing into funky territory on the update function, namely `simd` (via `packed_simd`); as a learning experiment, I'd strongly recommend it. It is currently nightly-only (it was stable until Rust 1.33, then it broke, and it's on the way to being stable again), but it's worth the hassle - we're talking 10-15x speedups. Due to the nature of the repetitive operation in SHA256, it is ideal for a 256bit (u32x8) vector.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback! The playground version also has the trait implementation you were talking about in your comment. I assume it's used to provide a clear (public) interface?

Comment: @AlexV Correct :-) it's also useful for benchmarking purposes - write a bench iterator requiring `T`, where `T` in this case would be that trait; from there, you can generate as many alternatives as you want provided they all implement the trait.

Comment: I did play around with your code a little bit (mainly copied it ;-) ) and timed it on my "reference ISO". Much to my suprise, it was about 8-10% slower than the original one (over multiple interleaved test runs with the original). After that, I created a [very simple criterion benchmark](https://gist.github.com/alexvorndran/2868f9efa4e60321289f0cc495798189) using the one million "a" string as input, which seems to also support that observation. Any thoughts on that? Maybe depending on the hardware?

Comment: @AlexV what platform are you on and how much can you `renice` the process? When I was benchmarking it I gave it realtime priority due to the bulk (90%+) of the time being spent in `update_block()` (and therefore, anything changed will be *extremely* small). I reckon it's worth digging into

Comment: This was on Windows 10 x64 on a 1st gen Core i5. I'm going to try to renice the benchmark (or the Windows equivalent thereof) once I get home and will also test on a Linux machine.

Comment: Still looking into this. Anyway, thanks for your feedback! I appreciate it very much.

Comment: @AlexV I forgot about this question :-( the reputation kicked me back into it. I'll be home in two hours and will have another proper look either later today or tomorrow.